# Undefined Window Error in Webpack-bundled React App

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, rollupjs

I've created a React component library called `prism` which I use in a React web app called `beacon`. `prism` is bundled using rollup, whereas `beacon` is bundled using `webpack`.

When I use the web app I'm getting the console error:

```
VM5253 main.js:1139 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'requestAnimationFrame')
    at eval (VM5329 index.js:31:477331)
    at eval (VM5329 index.js:31:477487)
    at prism/dist/esm/index.js (VM5253 main.js:1107:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM5253 main.js:1136:33)
    at fn (VM5253 main.js:1378:21)
    at eval (VM5328 Models.js:7:70)
    at ./src/components/views/Models.js (VM5253 main.js:118:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM5253 main.js:1136:33)
    at fn (VM5253 main.js:1378:21)
    at eval (VM5323 Router.js:10:75)
```

I think this must be because [`react-dimensions`](https://github.com/digidem/react-dimensions), which `prism` depends on, calls `window.requestAnimationFrame` ([here](https://github.com/digidem/react-dimensions/blob/master/index.jsx#L110)). But I don't understand why the `window` variable is undefined? Might someone be able to help?

**Interestingly, the error goes away if I specify `react-dimensions` as a peer-depedency in `prism`, and as a dependency in `beacon`. I'm not sure why that is, but I'd rather not do this.**

Thanks for any help!

##### Prism (React Component Library)

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "prism",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^3.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.6",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "rollup": "^4.9.5",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^6.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^6.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "fast-memoize": "^2.5.2",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.4.4",
    "rollup-plugin-inject": "^3.0.2",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "victory": "^36.8.1",
    "react-dimensions": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

`rollup.config.js`

```
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default {
    input: "src/index.js",
    output: [
        {
            file: packageJson.main,
            format: "cjs",
            sourcemap: "inline",
        },
        {
            file: packageJson.module,
            format: "esm",
            sourcemap: "inline",
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        commonjs({ include: /node_modules/ }),
        babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled' }),
        terser(),
        json(),
        image(),
        // below is important!
        resolve({browser: true}),
    ],
};
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

##### Beacon (Web app)

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "beacon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "prism": "1.0.2",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.2",
    "serve": "^14.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "serve -s public/ -l 3000",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server .",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.8",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.9.0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        filename: "main.js",
        publicPath: "/",
    },
    target: "web",
    devServer: {
        port: "3000",
        static: ["./public"],
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        liveReload: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'react': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
            'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-dom'),
        },

        fallback: {
            "fs": false,
            "tls": false,
            "net": false,
            "path": false,
            "zlib": false,
            "http": false,
            "https": false,
            "stream": false,
            "crypto": false,
            "util": false,
            "url": false,
            "assert": false,
            "tty": false,
            "os": false,
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/preset-react']},
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
        }),
        new Dotenv(".env.development"),
    ],

}
```